# how to populate multiple fields from a text_area in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

my model has four fields. So for the data entry I usually would do something like this

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :field1 %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :field1 %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :field2 %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :field2 %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :field3 %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :field3 %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :field4 %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :field4 %>
  </p>
  <p class="button"><%= f.submit %></p>
  <% end %>
```

I'd like to create a view with one text_area though, to enable mass data entry.

The idea would be to paste multiple lines each containing four fields separated by a comma into the text_area.

On submit I would then push the data into the DB.

How would a form like this look like?

Where would I the parse the content of the text_area and how would I save the data?

Thanks
Thomas

P.S. While everyone is thinking what to reply, I wonder if a calculated column would be a solution here. I mean there is nothing to calculate here, but at least I could create a form with a field from the model and on post split the data to the other fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is a virtual attribute. There is a very useful rails cast about there [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/16-virtual-attributes).

Basically, you would add a a field in your model, say called `mass_data`, and create getters and setters for it that convert to and from the `mass_data` format to four separate fields corresponding to your model. Then, you can add a text field in the form for that attribute just as if it was a real attribute.

i.e, in your controller, do this:

```
def mass_data
  [#{field1},#{field2},#{field3},#{field4}].join(',')
end

def mass_data=(data)
  split=mass_data.split(',')
  self.field1=split.first
  ...
  self.field4=split.last
end
```

and then just add a text field to the form view:

`<%= f.text_field :mass_data %>`

Comment: Thanks a lot Ankit, this is working just fine! The only question left I have is, if I can create multiple records by a single submit? I'd like to paste like 10 lines into the text_area, each line consisting of four fields. When I hit the submit button the app should add a record for each line in the text area, i.e. 10 lines, 10 records. Thanks Thomas

Comment: Did you manage the multiple record input? I need to do exactly the same.

Comment: I haven't tried this, but I think you could just create another virtual attribute, where the setter parses the 10 lines into 10 seperate mass_data records.